# BundleActivator methods not getting notified in OSGi

Tags: java, osgi, bundle

I have created a bundle with an activator. While starting my bundle the activator methods should be called but they aren't. I have implemented it in the same way as mentioned in the tutorial.

```
package com.manning.sdmia;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;


public class Activator implements BundleActivator { 
    private BundleContext context;

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In bundle");
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In stop");
    }
}
```

This is my `MANIFEST.MF` file:

```
enter code here
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Spring DM Hello World 
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.manning.sdmia.helloworld
Bundle-Version:1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: com.manning.sdmia.Activator
Export-Package:com.manning.sdmia
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
```

Now when I am starting the bundle from the OSGI prompt with the start command `System.out.println` should get called on start but it is not printing anything.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with what you have posted so far. Could you add details of what you typed in the shell, and what the output was? Were there any error messages?

Comment: Yes, please add some more details. Can you verify that the bundle is running?

Comment: True. Please add some more details. Are you using an IDE to run your OSGi environment or do you just start your framework via console. BTW, which framework do you use?

Comment: while installing it is giving me unknown as bundle name instead of com.manning.sdmia.helloworld and i am stating my framework from console and using equinox container

Comment: Did you find out whether or not your specific problem was caused by the manifest file? I [have a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13799093/590790), and it would be interesting for me if you provided feedback on this question. Perhaps my question is a duplicate of yours.

Answer (score 4):

If your manifest looks like you printed it here then it is not a proper manifest. Remove the first line and no spaces before the name of the header.

Comment: while installing it is giving me unknown as bundle name instead of com.manning.sdmia.helloworld.

Comment: So it sounds like your manifest is screwed ... use bnd to generate it, saves you from this stuff

Answer (score 2):

I've just had same problem and I made it work by adding this line to Manifest file:

```
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```