# Eclipse plugin bundle stuck in Starting state

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I used Eclipse to create a new plug-in project which created a default `Activator` for me. When debugging (running as Eclipse Application) I noticed the `start()` and `stop()` methods of this activator weren't called.

Following [the guide on what to do when your bundle isn't visible in Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Where_Is_My_Bundle) I stumbled upon the following results.

- Using the `ss` command, I can see my bundle listed.
- The status of my bundle is '[Starting](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#STARTING)'

> The bundle is in the process of starting. A bundle is in the `STARTING`
>   state when its `start` method is active. A bundle must be in this state
>   when the bundle's `BundleActivator.start(BundleContext)` is called. If
>   the `BundleActivator.start` method completes without exception, then the
>   bundle has successfully started and must move to the `ACTIVE` state.

A breakpoint placed on the first line in the `start` method doesn't get hit. Neither does `System.out.println` show up in the console. What could cause the `start` method not getting called, and thus the state being stuck in `STARTING`?

Comment: Has anything in your plugin actually been used at this point in the test? Are you trying to open one of your perspectives, editors, etc? Only when you try to use one of your plugin extensions is your startup code run.

Comment: @ChrisGerken That's an interesting comment, and possibly will turn out to be the answer. I'm intending to make a plugin which always has to run at startup, a 'service'. How could I force it to start? Additionally, why is the state `STARTING` and not `RESOLVED` then?

Comment: The idea was to minimize Eclipse startup time.  I'm not sure how to force the plugin to start other than to come up in a perspective supplied by the plugin.  I know that you can start your plugin as a headless app (as in a deployed Eclipse application). Perhaps there's a variant of those command line parameters you could use here.  That aside, it should be easy to see if your problem is lazy initialization.

Comment: I think you have "Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy" header in your MANIFEST.MF. If you remove that, it will behave like a regular OSGi bundle, and just start.

Comment: @FrankLee You are correct, I actually looked at this option before, and it seems [`lazy` is the only allowed option](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Bundle-ActivationPolicy), so I figured removing it wouldn't make a difference. I stopped investigating this issue since through the OSGi console, it did report the bundle was `STARTING`. I'll try out whether removing that line from the manifest changes anything.

Comment: @FrankLee At first I thought it didn't change anything, but in fact, now the status is set to `RESOLVED` instead of `STARTING`. Interesting, but it doesn't really help me out.

Comment: @StevenJeuris I can't believe I forgot about the Bundle-ActivationPolicy (: Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following doesn't address the fact that the OSGi console reports the plugin to be `STARTING`, but it is an approach by which I got my plugin to start right after Eclipse started up.

As [Chris Gerken points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799093/eclipse-plugin-bundle-stuck-in-starting-state#comment18982578_13799093), the startup code is only run when you try to use one of the plugin extensions.

Using the [`org.eclipse.ui.startup`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_startup.html) extension you can register a plugin that wants to be activated on startup. It is possible to set this up by using the manifest editor.

1. Add `org.eclipse.ui` as a dependency in the "Dependencies" tab.
2. In the "Extensions" tab add the Startup extension (`org.eclipse.ui.startup`).
3. Underneath "Extension Element Details" provide a class which implements `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup`.

[image: startup extension]

TaskManager.java

```
public class TaskManager implements IStartup
{
    @Override
    public void earlyStartup()
    {
        // This will get called when Eclipse is started,
        // after the GUI has been initialized.
    }
}
```